# Div disappears on positioning it fixed

Tags: html, css, positioning

My html is like this-;

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    this is the header
    <div class="hdr-lnks">
      <a href="#">home</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My css is this:

```
.hdr-lnks {
    position:fixed;
}
```

Why when I set `position: fixed`, does the div disappear?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You might have to declare where on the page you want it fixed.

For example, if you want it stuck to the top-left part of the page, your code might look like:

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    this is the header
    <div class="hdr-lnks">
      <a href="#">home</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hdr-lnks {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

[Here's a jsFiddle that illustrates it.](http://jsfiddle.net/Zxe7L/)